# Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface" - Unable to create a Run Configuration

Tags: android, eclipse

> I am working on the Android Development Tool with Eclipse IDE and unable to run my 
>   application correctly.

When I invoke the Run Configuration, I retrieve the following null pointer:

> Session Data - 
>   eclipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035
>   java.version=1.7.0_13
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>   BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
>   Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
>   Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse. > adt.package.product -clean

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at                 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.EmulatorConfigTab.createControl(EmulatorConfigTab.java:245)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.showInstanceTabsFor(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:806)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.displayInstanceTabs(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:737)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer$8.run(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.inputChanged(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:641)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput0(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:603)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:579)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.handleLaunchConfigurationSelectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:941)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog$3.selectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:560)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1226)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1251)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:256)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:433)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools$2.run(DebugUITools.java:600)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:608)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:542)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.OpenLaunchDialogAction.run(OpenLaunchDialogAction.java:81)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.OpenLaunchDialogAction.runWithEvent(OpenLaunchDialogAction.java:89)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:241)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar error. Check that your eclipse has the following situation:

Go to: Window > Preferences > Android, the SDK list is empty

If it is, I made the following tricks to solve it:

- stop eclipse
- Open file: open file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs
- Clean the value of property: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk (which currently contain your SDK path)
- start eclipse
- Go to: Window > Preferences > Android, enter the SDK path again > Click Apply. The SDK list should be loaded again.

The every should back to normal